# Cassandra Container Dynamic storage in host

Tags: database, docker, cassandra

I am working on cassandra containers and trying to find a way where cassandra's data can be stored on the host itself.

Is there any link or tutorial for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [`Mashape/docker-cassandra`](https://github.com/Mashape/docker-cassandra#using-a-custom-cassandra-configuration)

> ### Data storage
>
> This container also stores the actual storage data (usually in `/var/lib/cassandra/`) in a Data Volume. You can mount this volume from your host machine by doing so:

```
$ docker run -d \
    -v /path/to/your/var/lib/cassandra/:/var/lib/cassandra \
    -p 9042:9042 \
    --name cassandra \
    mashape/cassandra
```

That is one of the two VOLUMEs declared in [Cassandra Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/e57caf5f7dc58160846753096016f81224bc0a80/3.2/Dockerfile#L27-L35).

(in your case, replace `mashape/cassandra` by `cassandra:3.2`)

You can do the same with the Cassandra configuration (usually in `/etc/cassandra/`), which is also in a Data Volume.

```
    -v /path/to/your/etc/cassandra/:/etc/cassandra \
```